# Call dynamic library (C++) link with python-django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build an image-processing website using Django.  I've figured out how to upload the images, but I'm not sure how to call a C++ libraries to process the images.

I've tried using [CType](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to call the C++ libraries, but the link only explained how to call the libraries in console mode.  How would I put the results into a webpage?

I've uploaded [minimal example](https://github.com/doph/minimal-django-file-upload-example)  on github.

Answer (score 3):

> How would I put the results into a webpage?

[The same way you always do.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) Python is Python; adding `ctypes` and/or Django into the mix doesn't change that.